# Duration of an uploaded video in PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg, shell-exec

I need to know the duration of a video that I have uploaded to a page. I have written a PHP script for doing this:

```
<?php

$command = "ffmpeg -i video.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d ,; ";
$cm = shell_exec($command) ;
echo "$cm";

?>
```

When I execute this program via terminal it shows duration, but on calling it in a PHP page it does not give an output.
Please provide me a solution....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got error reporting turned on? Also, is the Apache / Web Server user allowed to run shell commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function shell_exec returns all the output in a string. exec just returns the last line.

Try with this

```
<?php

$command = "ffmpeg -i video.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d ,; ";
echo exec($command) ;

?>
```